# Understanding Methods

Tags: java

In the code below I have created a program that prints a triangle based on the number that the user inputs for the number of lines.

My questions is this: I am doing all of the computing in the main method, however how would I go about this by splitting this program up and putting the loops in their own method and calling it into the main method?

```
public class Triangle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


         //declare a scanner for user input 
         Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);



         System.out.print("Enter the number of lines: ");
          int numLines = input.nextInt();

          //include an if statement to make sure that the number of lines that 
           the user inputs is greater than zero
            if (numLines <= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Number of lines is negative. Exiting.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }


    //This for loops prints one line for each iteration.
    for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++)
    {
        //This for loop takes care of the preceding spaces in each line.
        for(int j=0;j<numLines-i-1;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        //This for loop prints the required number of characters in each line.
        for(int k=0;k<=i;k++)
            System.out.print("* ");

        //We are done with a line. Moving on to the next one.
        System.out.println();
    }


 }
}
```

Comment: Might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: [I downvoted because this question doesn't show any research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) - you can easily find this information in basic Java tutorials.

Comment: @user7 It would probably be downvoted there, too, for lacking research effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771936/print-every-prime-number-before-n-number
you did it here :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes. Even if the OP is updated with an approach, I don't think it is suited for SO. (since it is reviewing code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can also do it like this:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    // declare a scanner for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int getInput() { // method to take user input

        System.out.print("Enter the number of lines: ");
        int numLines = input.nextInt();

        // include an if statement to make sure that the number of lines that
        // the user inputs is greater than zero
        if (numLines <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Number of lines is negative. Exiting.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return numLines;
    }

    public void printTriangle() {
        int numLines = getInput();
        // This for loops prints one line for each iteration.
        for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
            // This for loop takes care of the preceding spaces in each line.
            for (int j = 0; j < numLines - i - 1; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            // This for loop prints the required number of characters in each
            // line.
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
                System.out.print("* ");

            // We are done with a line. Moving on to the next one.
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle obj = new Triangle(); // create object
        obj.printTriangle(); // call using object
    }
}
```

Here we are creating two functions :

- getInput()   To take input from user and return numLines to the caller.
- printTriangle() To print pattern

In the end we are creating an object of the Triangle class and calling the printTriangle().

```
Triangle obj = new Triangle(); // create object
        obj.printTriangle(); // call using object
```